# In this a form of selection bias?

Tags: sampling

**A complete rewrite of the question**.  Suppose a sample of size 100 from a population is made randomly and the sample is divided in groups $A$, $B$, $C$.  Group $A$ has size $50$, $B$ has size $30$ and $C$ has size $20$.  Clearly, group $A$ has $50$% of the sample.

**The original poster is a beginner**.  Perhaps the language is still not proper.  If you can, help me to use the proper language --- the objective here is to learn general principles of sampling a population.

**Question 1**. Am I introducing a selection bias into the sampling process if I increase this sample proportionally?  For instance, say I increase group $A$ to $55$, $B$ to $33$ and $C$ to $22$.

**Question 2**. Am I introducing a selection bias into the sampling process if I reduce this sample proportionally?  For instance, say I decrease group $A$ to $45$, $B$ to $27$ and $C$ to $18$.

**Question 3**.  Am I introducing a selection bias into the sampling process if I remove a single item from a single group?  For instance, say I decrease $C$ to $19$ while keeping $A$ at $50$ and $B$ at $30$.

Comment: This is a political and legal question rather than a statistical question.  Why is the vote invalid? In the UK, the reasons are essentially: lacking official stamp; no vote indicated; voting for more than one candidate; uncertainty of voter intention; and  writing or mark by which the voter can be identified.  None of these are arbitrary, though uncertainty and some of the others are often arguable in individual cases.

Comment: It is not a political or a legal question, so --- if it appears so ---, it could be rewritten so that only the design of the experiment appears.  I'm going to think of a different context in which the same argument could be presented --- elections could be a political thing.  What is meant by "invalid" vote in the question is a vote cast by a voter who is saying --- I don't want to vote on any candidate.  In many elections, such votes are considered invalid and are not counted towards anything --- it's as if they didn't exist.

Comment: If a voter does not want to vote for anybody, then it is a political question as to whether their invalid vote should be (a) ignored altogether as if they do not exist or (b) taken into account in whether the most popular candidate won sufficient votes to avoid a runoff election or (c) something else (see the [1962 Singaporean referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_Singaporean_integration_referendum) where blank votes - a quarter of those cast - were to be counted as "yes" to the most popular option proposed by the government).

Comment: You're right.  My objective however is to know whether there is a sampling-no-no involved in the typical argument.  So, yes, I think you're helping me to converge on what I'm looking for.  In ``Statistics'' by David Freedman, Robert Pisani, and Roger Purves, chapter 19 is about sampling.  They say in section 1 of chapter 19: "Estimating parameters from the sample is justified when the sample represents the population. [...] the method of choosing the sample matters a lot [...] the best methods involve the planned introduction of chance [...]"

Comment: In the same section, we also read "[a] sampling procedure should be fair, selecting people for inclusion in the sample in an impartial way, so as to get a representative cross section of the public. A systematic tendency on the part of the sampling procedure to exclude one kind of person or another from the sample is called selection bias."  That gives me a name I didn't have before --- selection bias.

Comment: This is such a radical rewrite of the original question that I fear answers to it might not address the real question you have. My stance is that, no, none of these introduce selection bias the way that I would typically think about sampling, but you don’t seem to be thinking that way. It would be helpful to you to carefully define your terms as you intend to use them (regardless of how that aligns with established terminology in statistics), which might involve a discussion of the original context of elections.

Comment: How, exactly, does one go about changing the sizes of these groups?  At the outset you have stipulated that they are *random* outcomes of the sample.

Comment: What is the role of these groups? What do you want to do with your sample? It reads as if you take your sample and then divide it into the groups (randomly?) but you may also mean that these groups already exist in the population, then you draw your sample and find the the group composition of the sample is as you state. Or the groups already exist and you can control them and therefore fix in advance the numbers of objects in the groups that you then sample?

Comment: @ChristianHennig, the second option.  These groups already exist in the population, then I draw the sample and find the the group composition of the sample is as I stated.  (Thanks!)

Comment: @whuber, your answer seems quite coherent.  These groups cannot be changed in any way at all --- not even proportionally, as I tried.  Would that be called an "extrapolation"?

Comment: @user401250 Add any relevant information to the question and not only in the comments. If you draw the sample and then find the group composition (which is random if I understand it correctly), how can you achieve proportional increase as in Question 1? Or are you asking us to assume that this has happened with a random draw of additional objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sampling will no longer be random, given that you select samples on a criteria you do not mention, so in this sense you would have selection bias (but once we said that, we still have to consider if this is a problem, or not).

If your goal is to estimate the proportion of A, B, C in the population, it would obviously make no sense to draw additional observations with pre-determined specific proportions of A, B, and C. This could be the answer to your first two questions, but your question doesn't mention if estimating proportions in the population from a sample is your goal.

Relative to your third question, you can have very good reasons to discard some observations, so potential selection bias is not the sole thing to consider. In surveys, it can happen that some people answer multiple times to a survey when they shouldn't (e.g. because they made an error, or because they want to bias the results, or because they get money each time they answer), or that people outside of the population of interest incorrectly participated in the survey.

In the context of complex survey sampling, [it can also make sense to voluntarily oversample some categories](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2016/10/25/oversampling-is-used-to-study-small-groups-not-bias-poll-results/).

You could also be in a situation where you're not interested in inference from a sample, but you are directly measuring the whole population of interest. Consider the case of census or elections. As your goal is not inference from a sample, but retrieving data from all the population, the question of bias does not make really sense.

In this case, the question is rather if the data collection process is adequate to avoid various problems, like fraud, incorrectly interpreting some ambiguous votes or responses, or not getting data from some parts of the population that would make an important difference or could lead to some *de facto* disenfranchisement (all this considering the cost efficiency of the data collection process at the same time; it may be reasonable to object to re-run an election over a dozen of dubious votes out of millions, if they would change nothing to the result). How to make an election process fair would rather be a question for https://politics.stackexchange.com.